# Can we exclude setting http header Content-type:application/json from the request?

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to create postman collection request using Postman plugin from Chrome.

The preview of the request looks like:

```
PUT /api/20130409/system/users/618a9ff389bc4bcda22e20150f818d78 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:81
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "User": { "UserName": "updated1", } }
```

And then, I removed the `Content-Type` header from the request, and set the ServiceStack's `DefaultContentType` property with "application/json".

#### Question 1:

Does the ServiceStack supposed to interpret the request content as JSON ? (it fails on my box)

My understanding is the `DefaultContentType` is about setting the "Accept" header on the request. If the request doesn't have "Accept" header set with a particular value like `"Application/json"` or `"Application/xml"` then the response content will default to the value what ever is set on the property `DefaultContentType`.

If my understanding as said above is correct...

#### Question 2:

Does the request always need to set with proper `Content-Type` header in `PUT/POST` scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the default content type, but you can modify and assing the content type in you want in the host configuration, try the following:

```
 DefaultContentType = ContentType.Json
```

you can select xml as well.

Comment: I set it programmatically  SetConfig(                      
                new EndpointHostConfig
                    {                        
                        DefaultContentType = ContentType.Json
                    }); But still I need to add the Content-Type header in my request, otherwise it fails

Comment: @RajYennam also see the [Content Negotiation Section](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#content-negotiation) on the Routing wiki for alternate ways to ask for different content types.